# ld: file not found: /usr/lib/libextension.dylib

Tags: dylib, marmalade

ld: file not found: /usr/lib/libextension.dylib

Can some one help me to find this file. I can`t work without it. Its is used to make a .ipa when deploying marmalade project.

Answer (score 0):

This file is relative to the application path from where your iOS SDK is installed. For instance, the full path might look like this:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk/usr/lib/libextension.dylib

If it cannot be found, a new installation of the iPhoneOS SDK could have relocated it. Some of the newer Xcode updates will remove older iPhoneOS SDKs as well which might still be referenced.

Try searching for lib extension.dylib from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhonseOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/